# Trying to remember this manga or anime that is very similar to "8th son are you kidding me?"

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

He is born in a poor noble family; a succession issue might occur, I think, if they find out he is a magic user or something. His brother teaches him how to shoot with a bow, but mc becomes op with it. Then eventually MC goes to adventure school makes friends with a swordsman, saves 2 girls and they join his party.

I'm pretty sure the mc has an interdimensional bag as well to carry all his stuff. Extremely similar to the anime mentioned in the title I know, but I only remembered the details after watching the first episode of 8th son.

However, his brothers all left at the start, so yea not sure which manga, one of the brothers stayed behind and taught him archery before he too had to go because he got older and had to leave the family to make money.

Comment: Is this a reincarnation/transmigration story, like 8th son? Or is he just a native of this land?

Comment: I think he is a reincarnation/transmigration type MC, but I'm not sure if I recall exactly. All I can remember at the moment like I said, he is in a poor nobility like 8th son. He is atleast 3rd son+ because first son marries and his other brothers leave I think aside from the one that stayed because he was either young and had couple more years to go. He stayed and trained the MC some archery, MC eventually got good at it and brought in some chicken or animals for food instead of that poor meals they have been eating. Eventually MC leaves for adventure school and already had a warrior friend.

Comment: Was this in full color or black&white? Do you remember when you read this?